# Incorrectly breaking out of a python while loop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I am trying to build a Twitter filter app that searches your personal timeline of people you follow/RTs from people you follow from keywords of your choosing. (That's not the question, that's the background... I'm not up to that yet, I'm just playing around with the API at the moment!)

I'm just starting to learn Python, I'm previously a Java programmer and I'm wondering how to check user input for valid... well, input!

I have a numbered menu (currently with just 2 items in) and I want the user to type 1 or 2 and if they don't, for it to throw an error message and loop back to the input.  I'm currently getting the error message of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Filtwer.py", line 31, in <module>
    if "1" in menuselect:
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable
```

Where line 31 is the start of the if statement in the code block below.  I'm not sure if I'm missing something? Not breaking out of the while loop correctly for example? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks :)

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='<redacted>',
                  consumer_secret='<redacted>',
                  access_token_key='<redacted>',
                  access_token_secret='<redacted>')

while True:
    menuselect = input("1. Tweet\n2. Get Tweets\n...: ")
    if menuselect == 1 or 2: break
    print "Please enter a valid entry!"

if "1" in menuselect:
    statusinput = raw_input("Tweet: ")
    status = api.PostUpdate(statusinput)
    print "Sucessfully tweeted!"

else:
    timeline5 = api.GetUserTimeline(user_id=<my_twitter_ID>, screen_name='<my_twitter_screenname>', count=5, include_rts='true')
    print [s.text for s in timeline5]
```

**Edit:**

Got it to work like this (included comments to show how my answer differed from the answer I chose as correct. Thanks for the help guys! :) )

```
while True:
#try:
    menuselect = raw_input("1. Tweet\n2. Get Tweets\n...: ")
    if menuselect == "1" or menuselect == "2": break
#catch ValueError:
#   pass
#finally:
    print "Please enter a valid entry!"

if "1" == menuselect:
[...]
```

Comment: `if menuselect == 1 or 2: break` should be `if menuselect in (1, 2): break`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if `menuselect` is `1`, you should use `==` operator NOT `in` operator. (Because `in` operator is used to check the member existence)

```
if 1 == menuselect:
```

**Note:** Also, don't use `input` function in Python 2.x, to get input from the user (because of the security concerns). Use `raw_input` instead and convert the result to `int` manually, like this

```
menuselect = int(raw_input("1. Tweet\n2. Get Tweets\n...: "))
```

**Note 2:** You might want to use `in` operator in the `break` condition (it is correct here, because you are checking whether the value of `menuselect` is one of the possible values), like this

```
if menuselect in (1, 2): break
```

because

```
if menuselect == 1 or 2:
```

will always evaluate to `True`, as it is evaluated as `(menuselect == 1) or 2`, even if `menuselect` is not 1, the `2` part will make the expression evaluate to Truthy.

**Edit:** To get around the exception part, when a string is entered instead of integers, you can use `try..except` like this

```
while True:
    try:
        menuselect = input("1. Tweet\n2. Get Tweets\n...: ")
        if menuselect int (1, 2): break
    catch ValueError:
        pass
    finally:
        print "Please enter a valid entry!"
```

Comment: I've changed it to that, but it's still breaking out of the while loop early.  Now if you type anything except a 1, it goes to the 'else' and gets the last 5 tweets from my profile.

Comment: @AutomatedRandomated Please check the `Note 2` in my answer.

Comment: Ah okay, that `if menuselect in(1, 2): break` fixes the issue with a non-valid integer, but what if someone tries to type a char or string.  It now throws an error if a non-int is entered?

Comment: @AutomatedRandomated Isn't that what you want? How do you want to handle that?

Comment: I want for it to loop back to the menu and give a user-friendly "Enter a proper answer" message. Currently if you type anything but an int, it gives an error and ends the script.

Comment: @AutomatedRandomated When a string is entered instead of number, a `ValueError` is thrown by `int` function, you can except it like I have shown in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it to work by just taking it as a string input as per my edited post above. Does that look like a valid way of doing it?

Comment: @AutomatedRandomated Good. That looks okay :)

Answer (score 1):

Another problem you have is with this line:

```
if menuselect == 1 or 2: break
```

Python interprets this as

```
if (menuselect == 1) or 2: break
```

Meaning it checks if `menuselect` is one, and if it is false, it checks if `2` is true. In python, non-zero numbers are interpreted as true, so this condition will always be true.

Change this to either

```
if menuselect in [1, 2]: break
```

or the more lengthy

```
if menuselect == 1 or menuselect == 2: break
```